# Python - running pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I created a simple game using Pygame. Is it possible to run this game on other computer, where Pygame is not installed? 
I tried to write a BATCHT file, which installs Pygame using pip. But it isn't working too.

Comment: If your target machine runs Windows, you can try [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your game run in other computer where there is no pygame installed you need to make it executable. Following package can make your script executable:

1. [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
2. [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

**Tutorial**

1. [Converting to executable using pyinstaller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOIJIk_maO4)
2. [Converting to executable using py2exe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKQ1Ph81Gps)

Pyinstaller is way more easier than py2exe. But both of them works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try to build a dist, in case your target system is linux based (.rpm or .deb). You find a detailed description here:

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html

Answer (score 1):

Try auto-py-to-exe (https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)
With this you can pack the whole thing into an exe.
It supports everything above python 2.7